# Como gerar número sequencial automaticamente no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário para inscrição em um processo seletivo e após o usuário enviar os dados de cadastro gostaria de gerar o número de inscrição no seguinte formato: 00012018.
Encontrei somente uma resposta pra isso mas não funcionou.

Rails 5.

Comment: Dê mais informações, como códigos que você tentou até o momento.

Comment: Você terá que identificar qual é o padrão no número de inscrição.
No número que você colocou tem 8 caracteres, depois tem um número (1) e depois tem o ano(2018).
Aí você vai contatenar essas informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse `00012018` que você quer não precisa ser persistido, e pode ser utilizado somente para visualização. Para fazer isso, pode implementar um método no modelo.

```
class Inscricao < ApplicationRecord
  def numero_inscricao
    return nil unless self.persisted?

    id_com_zeros = "%04d" % self.id
    "#{id_com_zeros}#{self.created_at.year}"
  end
end
```

Isso te dará:

```
foo.numero_inscricao
=> "00012018"
```

Como ele utiliza o `#created_at`, vai funcionar pelos próximos anos e para os registros que já estão no banco, por ser uma função executada em memória.

Só tenha certeza de que o ID é um inteiro e não um UUID, como é possível.

- [ruby-doc.org: String formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-25)

Comment: Vlwsssssss, deu certo o///